# Highcharts export chart using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, phantomjs

I am currently working to export the charts using highcharts. Highcharts has introduced export using node.js as mentioned in the link below. https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/256-introducing-the-highcharts-node-js-export-server/
In the website above they have mentioned that "The CLI mode also replaces the old highcharts-convert.js PhantomJS script"
 But the link below clearly states they use phantom js.
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server
Do they use the in memory browser 'phantom js' internally to render charts?

Answer (score 1):

Look dependencies at https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/package.json for highcharts-export-server package

They use phantomjs-prebuilt package.